# SSRS report on MySQL with parameters

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, parameters

I am using SSRS to connect to a MySQL database.

My query is based on parameters.
But the query itself is built on separate steps and has internal parameters that are based on outputs from the first parameters passed into the query.

I saw that I need to replace the input parameters with question marks.
How do I handle the other parameters?
Also, is there an issue using multi-step queries in this setup?

Do I need to re-write the query to get rid of the internal parameters and multi-steps?

I don't know if this will be totally possible as I am using @csum := @csum + tran.

Comment: You handle the internal parameters the same as you would if you were not using SSRS at all.   Declare and use them within the same query-context.

Comment: So is the issue the multi step procedure?

Comment: I don't know that there is an issue, are you getting an error?

Comment: @TabAlleman, I wasn't able to get it to work with the multi-step procedure. It either said that there were no resulting columns, or gave other errors. So I broke it down into steps, and stored the values in temp tables on MS SQL between each step. Thanks for your help.